TensorFlow: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
I am running TensorFlow on Windows 11 Home. When I enter python -m pip install tensorflow I see that the library has installed properly. When I enter python -m pip check tensorflow I see the following message:
No broken requirements found.

However when I try to run import tensorflow as tf I get the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jarzi\venv312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 70, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jarzi\venv312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\jarzi\venv312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 85, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jarzi\venv312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 70, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

I have checked this link this link but couldn't find the error that I encountered.
Any suggestions? I found some other questions on this error in this site but they don't have any great answers and didn't solved my problem.
